# facebook test app is not working with another users id

Tags: php, facebook

I have developed a test facebook app. Its working fine if I login and access it but if another user login and use the same app it creating error... what could be the issue.

Comment: What would be the error?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have the Application in Sandbox mode:

> If enabled, only the developers of
>   your app will be able to sign in to
>   your app

You need to add that "other" user at least as a *Tester* in your Application's "Manage Users" section under the **About** tab.

More about access levels can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity).